# How to restrict user to create tables/views in a particular schema

Tags: sql-server

I want particular users with same level of access in public role to be able to just create tables/views in their individual schemas. As in user1 in user1_schema, user2 in user2_schema and restrict user1 from creating table in user2_schema
I am using mssql-server

Comment: `ALTER` permission on the schema is required to create objects in the schema, which non-privileged users won't have by default. Have you granted `ALTER` on the other schems to the user/role.

Comment: The users have only got alter on the schemas they have access to. Other schemas no alter permission is granted. I need them to be restricted from creating any new schemas in the db